# componentWillUnmount() not being called when refreshing the current page

Tags: reactjs

I've been having this problem where my code in the `componentDidMount()` method wasn't firing properly when refreshing the current page (and subsequently, the component). However, it works perfectly fine just navigating and routing through my website by clicking links. Refresh the current page? Not a chance.

I found out that the problem is that `componentWillUnmount()` doesn't trigger when I refresh the page and triggers fine clicking links and navigating my website/app.

The triggering of the `componentWillUnmount()` is crucial for my app, since the data that I load and process in the `componentDidMount()` method is very important in displaying information to users.

I need the `componentWillUnmount()` to be called when refreshing the page because in my `componentWillMount()` function (which needs to re-render after every refresh) I do some simple filtering and store that variable in a state value, which needs to be present in the `logos` state variable in order for the rest of the component to work. This does not change or receive new values at any time during the component's life cycle.

```
componentWillMount(){
  if(dataReady.get(true)){
    let logos = this.props.questions[0].data.logos.length > 0 ? this.props.questions[0].data.logos.filter((item) => {
      if(item.logo === true && item.location !== ""){
        return item;
      }
    }) : [];
    this.setState({logos: logos});
  }
};
```

**Cliffs:**

- I do DB filtering in `componentWillMount()`method
- Need it to be present in the component after refresh
- But I have a problem where the `componentWillUnmount()` doesn't trigger when the page is refreshed
- Need help
- Please

Comment: I can't really see why you are trying to do things like this.. if you wan't the state to persist after refresh, you should save your state for example into local storage every time the state changes.

Comment: @Hardy The props above is a database collection already. The filtering is just so I don't have to make unnecessary DB calls when it can be done very fast before the component loads.

Comment: So how this `componentWillUnmount` would help you? Don't really get it.. why not just save the filter to local storage when it's applied and check in `componentWillMount` if the filter is there, if not, use the default one.. or even cache the filtered data..

Comment: Because if the component doesn't unmount from the DOM, my componentWillMount doesn't trigger. I could save it to DB, but really don't feel like making DB calls that don't have to be called, unless I can get this to work. But I didn't try the local storage route. Maybe that will work as you described.

Answer (score 89):

When the page refreshes react doesn't have the chance to unmount the components as normal. Use the [`window.onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) event to set a handler for refresh (read the comments in the code):

```
class Demo extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);

        this.componentCleanup = this.componentCleanup.bind(this);
    }

    componentCleanup() { // this will hold the cleanup code
        // whatever you want to do when the component is unmounted or page refreshes
    }

    componentWillMount(){
      if(dataReady.get(true)){
        let logos = this.props.questions[0].data.logos.length > 0 ? this.props.questions[0].data.logos.filter((item) => {
          if(item.logo === true && item.location !== ""){
            return item;
          }
        }) : [];

        this.setState({ logos });
      }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
      window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.componentCleanup);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.componentCleanup();
        window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', this.componentCleanup); // remove the event handler for normal unmounting
    }

}
```

**useWindowUnloadEffect Hook**

I've extracted the code to a reusable hook based on [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect):

```js
// The hook

const { useEffect, useRef, useState } = React

const useWindowUnloadEffect = (handler, callOnCleanup) => {
  const cb = useRef()
  
  cb.current = handler
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const handler = () => cb.current()
  
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', handler)
    
    return () => {
      if(callOnCleanup) handler()
    
      window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', handler)
    }
  }, [callOnCleanup])
}


// Usage example
  
const Child = () => {
  useWindowUnloadEffect(() => console.log('unloaded'), true)
  
  return <div>example</div>
}

const Demo = () => {
  const [show, changeShow] = useState(true)

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => changeShow(!show)}>{show ? 'hide' : 'show'}</button>
      {show ? <Child /> : null}
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo />,
  root
)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: My problem is that the component doesn't unmount after refreshing the page. So the `componentWillUnmount` isn't even called.

Comment: However, `window.onbeforeunload` will be called instead. The `window.onbeforeunload = null` in the `componentWillUnmount` is just to remove the event if normal routing takes place.

Comment: I'll try this. Thanks.

Comment: @OriDrori : This should actually be done using event listeners as to not override any other events you may want to fire on unload. In addition you should not fire events in `componentWillMount` that rely on the DOM already being loaded as this will break on server side rendering- use `componentDidMount` instead.

**componentDidMount**
    `window.addEventListener("beforeunload", () => {
          this.componentCleanUp()
    });`


**componentWillUnmount**
    `window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", () => {
          this.componentCleanUp()
    });`

Comment: @BenBud - good points with the componentDidMount, and using addEventListener. I've updated the answer. One thing to note, however, is that you have to use the same instance of the function in `addEventListener`, and `removeEventListener` to actually removed the event handler, so don't use 2 arrow functions.

Comment: @OriDrori Good catch :-)

Comment: Looks like this line

`window.addEventListener('removeEventListener', this.componentCleanup);`

should be

    `window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', this.componentCleanup);`

Comment: Why `beforeunmount` instead of `unmount`?

Comment: You mean `beforeunload` and `unload`. In this case just a matter of habit. Since we don't try to stop close/refresh unload will work as well.

Comment: instead of using window.removeEventListener, you can set the callback to be fired only once using:
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.componentCleanup, {once: true})

Comment: @o.z - this won't work because the the handler won't be called when the component is unmounted. This is why we need to explicitly remove it.

Comment: @OriDrori so the callback will be fired but it won't be removed?
The problem is that componentWillUnmount() isn't called when refreshing the web page

Comment: You need the `beforeunload` event handler for refresh, and you need the `componentWillUnmount()` to handle changes that are not refresh. In addition `componentWillUnmount()` should remove the `beforeunload` to prevent future refreshes from calling it, while the component doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 12):

I also run into this problem and realised that I needed to make sure that at least 2 components will always gracefully unmount. So I finally did a High Order Component that ensures the wrapped component is always unmounted

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react'

// this high order component will ensure that the Wrapped Component
// will always be unmounted, even if React does not have the time to
// call componentWillUnmount function
export default function withGracefulUnmount(WrappedComponent) {

    return class extends Component {

        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state = { mounted: false };
            this.componentGracefulUnmount = this.componentGracefulUnmount.bind(this)
        }


        componentGracefulUnmount(){
            this.setState({mounted: false});

            window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', this.componentGracefulUnmount);
        }

        componentWillMount(){
            this.setState({mounted: true})
        }

        componentDidMount(){
            // make sure the componentWillUnmount of the wrapped instance is executed even if React
            // does not have the time to unmount properly. we achieve that by
            // * hooking on beforeunload for normal page browsing
            // * hooking on turbolinks:before-render for turbolinks page browsing
            window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.componentGracefulUnmount);
        }

        componentWillUnmount(){
            this.componentGracefulUnmount()
        }

        render(){

            let { mounted }  = this.state;

            if (mounted) {
                return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
            } else {
                return null // force the unmount
            }
        }
    }

}
```

*Note*:  If like me, you are using turbolinks and rails, you might wanna hook on both `beforeunload` and `turbolinks:before-render` events.

Comment: I've run into this problem on 2 projects so I decided to extract the code to small package : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-graceful-unmount

Answer (score 0):

I see that this question has over a thousand views, so I'll explain how I solved this problem:

To solve this particular problem, the most sensible way is to create an upper level component that loads your subscription or database, so that you load the required data before passing it to your child component, which would completely remove the need to use `componentWillMount()`. Also, you can do the computations in the upper level component and just pass them down as props to use in your receiving component

For example:

```
class UpperLevelComponent extends React.Component {

render() {
if(this.props.isReady) {
return(<ChildComponent {...props}/>)
}
}
}

export default createContainer(() => {
const data = Meteor.subscribe("myData");
const isReady = data.ready();

return {
isReady,
data: MyData.find.fetch()
}
})
```

In the example above, I use Meteor's reactive container to get my MongoDB data and wait for it to completely finish subscribing before I render the child component, passing it any props I want. If you load all your data in the higher level component, you won't have to rely on the `componentWillMount()` method to trigger after every refresh. The data will be ready in the upper level component, so you can use it however you want in the child component.