# Stopping a function from componentDidMount() after going to a different url

Tags: reactjs

I have called a function in a stateful component like this

```
  handleScroll = (event) => {
  if (window.scrollY < 201){
    var pxScrolled = window.scrollY;
    var opValue = (200 - pxScrolled)*0.005;
    document.getElementById("blogpost").firstChild.style.opacity = opValue;
  }
  if (window.scrollY > 201){
    document.getElementById("blogpost").firstChild.style.opacity = "0";
  }
}

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  }
```

But now when I change the url and go to a different page the function is still running and i get

TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null

how do i keep the function just in one component?

Not sure if this is enough information if you need additional info I will supply

Comment: Did you try to remove the event listener in `componentWillUnmount`?

Comment: [removeEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) `componentWillUnmount() {window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll)}`

Answer (score 0):

`componentDidUnmount` is not called if you refresh a page, or if the browser is closed, or changing the URL via the browser. Basically Unmount is something React does when a component is removed from the hierarchy by programmatically..ie, with conditional rendering, react-router routing, etc.

If this is something you want to support you might want to implement something like this [componentWillUnmount() not being called when refreshing the current page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39084924/componentwillunmount-not-being-called-when-refreshing-the-current-page).

Answer (score 0):

You need to clean up and remove your event listener in the `componentWillUnmount` method of your component. This will cancel the scroll event listener when the component is about to be removed from the page—which, it seems, will happen if the URL is changed.

For example:

```js
componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
}
```

In general all event listeners that are added in `componentDidMount` methods should be removed in `componentWillUnmount` methods.