# the componentWillUnmount problem of BrowserRouter

Tags: reactjs

The code is as follows:

```
export default class AppRouter extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <App>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path='/home' exact component={Home}></Route>
                    </Switch>
                </App>
            </BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        localStorage.setItem('flag', `${Math.random()}：App is unload`)
    }

ReactDOM.render(
    <AppRouter />,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

when I refresh the page, the process of componentWillUnmount will not trigger, i can not set the flag in the localStorage. Actual I want to save some data in the localStorage, but i find this problem, so can you give me some answers about this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39084924/componentwillunmount-not-being-called-when-refreshing-the-current-page)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [componentWillUnmount() not being called when refreshing the current page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39084924/componentwillunmount-not-being-called-when-refreshing-the-current-page)