# React doesn't unmount component when browser back or forward buttons are clicked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

when back or forward buttons are clicked, react doesn't trigger `componentWillUnmount()` life cycle method. I already found this same [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39084924/componentwillunmount-not-being-called-when-refreshing-the-current-page) when page refreshes, but what I need to do is to identify event relevant to browser back or forward button clicks. For the page refresh issue, it uses [window.onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) event to trigger the relevant cleanUp functionality when document is going to be unloaded. But I want to trigger the necessary functionality when back or forward buttons are clicked and not during page refresh. Therefore, how can I approach this issue ?

Comment: When browser back/forward button is clicked, window url changes. maybe use a url listener hook like `useLocation`?

Comment: `useLocation` hook returns the location object that represents the current URL and it won't be possible to identify URL change inside the same component. And it also won't be triggered when the component is going to be unmounted by clicking on forward or backward button.